# Design tips for large database table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design, orm

I have a huge database table (millions of records). Currently our app is based only in Canada but now we are entering other countries so millions of data per country will be added. Should I create separate tables per country or keep one huge table?
I am using Cakephp 2.x, mysql 5.6
There will be many read and write operations on this table. 
Issue with separate table is that since I use models (MVC) for database operations, I will have to create separate models per country and combining them for reports purposes will be mess.
On other hand, keeping everything in one table will be very heavy on the system. Will indexing help in this case?

Comment: Look into [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html).

Comment: @marekful I am storing country code (ca, us). And partitioning can't be done with text key I think. Should I change it to numeric values instead? (1 for ca, 2 for us etc)

Comment: Topicstarter if you follow @marekful suggestion make sure to use LIST as [Partitioning Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-list.html) assuming the countries are based on country_id's

Comment: "Should I change it to numeric values instead? (1 for ca, 2 for us etc)" Yes ideally you should have a country table with names and the id's and have a country_id column in your data table.

Comment: At some point, you should consider engaging professional help. I think you might be at that point.

Comment: It's simply far to broad to be answered in any meaningful way. "Many" is not clear, Cake has nothing to do with the problem at all. Millions, even billions of records aren't a problem for any modern SQL DB if it was designed properly. Oh, and I also disagree with @RaymondNijland, instead of Ids use 2 or 3 char ISO 3166-1 codes.

Comment: "And I also disagree with ... instead of IDs use 2 or 3 char ISO 3166-1 codes. " well @burzum i believe there are 195 countries in the world meaning you can fit it in a unsigned TINYINT which is 1 byte storage **always** vs a two or three bytes storage (CHAR datatype) (or more depending of the used charset/collate) so the data saving can be "great" for millions/billions of records..

Comment: "Millions, even billions of records aren't a problem for any modern SQL DB if it was designed properly." @burzum you mean **indexed** properly right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't consider a few extra bytes a problem these days, especially when you deal with something like CQRS for example were you might have a relational DB for your write model and ES or MongoDB for your read model. Of course you'll "waste" space but gain other advantages. The world isn't binary, there are shades of gray. ;) And I meant the overall design, not just indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Common question; common answer:  Do *not* make lots of 'identical' tables.

Do not use `PARTITION` except for a very few types of queries.  The most common is a sliding time scale where 'old' rows need to be periodically deleted (via `DROP PARTITION`).  `PARTITIONing` rarely helps `SELECT` performance.

(A billion rows is "huge"; millions is quite viable.)

Indexing is *mandatory* for any non-trivial database table!

Use `country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  That's 2 bytes (nearly as small as a 1-byte `TINYINT`, and a lot more human-friendly.  Sure, that 1MB for a million rows; but look at another way -- it is about 1% of the size of the table, which possibly takes ~100 bytes/row.

As for "indexed right" -- You *must* start with the `SELECTs` to figure out what index(es) are needed.

You mentioned "reports".  That may get into needing to build and maintain Summary Tables.  (Again, let's see the `SELECTs`.)

Comment: That means I shouldn't use partitioning and also should keep in one table? Is Indexing enough to optimize select queries?

Comment: @ParthPatel - No one can answer that withing seeing the `SELECTs` (and `UPDATEs` if they are non-trivial).  I can write design a 2-row table plus a `SELECT` that will take hours, then crash the server.  (But you won't do that, will you?).....   And I can show you queries that run in 10 _milliseconds_ on a _billion-row_ table.